# Why does adding jQuery animations to my site make CSS media queries do not work?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, animation

I recently implemented this jQuery animation script:

```
$(window).load(function() {
    if (window.innerWidth > 700){
        $(window).scroll(function() {
            $('#animate').each(function(){
            var imagePos = $(this).offset().top;

            var topOfWindow = $(window).scrollTop();
                if (imagePos < topOfWindow+800) {
                    $(this).addClass("expandUp");
                }
            });
        });
        $(window).scroll(function() {
            $('#animate1').each(function(){
            var imagePos = $(this).offset().top;

            var topOfWindow = $(window).scrollTop();
                if (imagePos < topOfWindow+800) {
                    $(this).addClass("expandUp");
                }
            });
        });
        $(window).scroll(function() {
            $('#animate2').each(function(){
            var imagePos = $(this).offset().top;

            var topOfWindow = $(window).scrollTop();
                if (imagePos < topOfWindow+800) {
                    $(this).addClass("expandUp");
                }
            });
        });
    }   
});
```

Now when I load the page the animations work but my media queries do not. The jQuery is firing off CSS that i got from here: [Animations](http://www.justinaguilar.com/animations/css/animations.css)

Can anyone explain why this script would stop my media queries from working completely?

Example of my media query that is not working:

```
@media screen and (max-width:568px){

    .resource {
        width: 100%;
        margin-right: 0;
        min-height: 0;
    }

    #skill-info .fa {
        font-size: 50px;
    }

    .navbar-brand {
        position: absolute;
        margin-left: -115px;
        left: 50%;
        display: block;
    }

    h1{
        color: orange;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please add a jsfiddle.

Comment: As I see the script runs for widths(innerWIdth) > 700px so it shouldn't interfere with anything

Comment: @A1rPun Your edit wasn't well formatted so I improved it. What is the issue? Just edit again if I overwrote something.

Comment: Use your browser dev tools to inspect the css rules that apply to any element in page in order of rule ranking. animations add inline css which may be overriding the stylesheet rules.

Comment: @Turnip I've edited the changes which were lost in the process.. I improved another edit and the formatting was just right (same as your edit)

Comment: F12 to open the dev tools and look at the Console. Any errors reported?

Comment: You will notice that Javascript does not create stylesheets, so it is applying all the changes on the elements themselves. Since inline styles have a higher precedence than external styles, it will overwrite anything defined in your stylesheets.

Comment: There are no console errors or jQuery errors. I the jQuery script should not  add inline styles, only classes to the elements. Even if it did add inline styling, the added classes do not apply to the elements that are being styled in my media queries.  I'm so confused